# Why Do I Get an nginx Internal Server Error 500 on a PNG Image File Upload

Tags: nginx, file-upload, sinatra

For some reason I'm getting a `Internal Server Error 500` on `nginx` when I upload a `png` file to my site.  The site works with a `jpg` or `jpeg` file.  I am getting nothing in the error log at all.  My mime.types holds the following:

```
image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
image/png                             png;
```

Since I'm getting no feedback at all, I have nothing to place here as more information on the error.  The only `nginx.conf` directives with regards to uploads is this:

```
client_max_body_size    12M;
```

I am guessing it is `nginx` that's having this issue because the application is handling the other file types (`jpg`, `jpeg`) and error reporting shows I'm not even getting to my `route` in `Sinatra`.  I've looked for some kind of file type directives in the `nginx` directives list, and found nothing.

How can I get this file type to be received properly?  Why is `nginx` not happy with this file submission?

Comment: Did you check your error log? Depends on your Linux distribution, but it is should be at `/var/log/nginx/errors.log`.

Comment: First place I went to.   Absolutely nothing in there.  I'm on OSX.

Comment: Can you try to upload when you have stopped your sinatra process, so we can make sure that error is on the Nginx side?

Comment: Plus, have you enough disk space? Or maybe there is a permission issue with the folder that your file is getting uploaded to.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Permissions are fine.  I can upload `.jpg` files just fine.  Also that would show up in the log as a permissions error.  I can't stop Sinatra and upload.  The site is driven by Sinatra.  The target disk has over 20 GB free space, as it's my workstation.

Comment: Hi Rich. In a terminal, try `curl --verbose -F 'data=@path/to/local/file' UPLOAD_ADDRESS` (you need the at-sign) and see what you get, `curl` is invaluable for this kind of thing.

Comment: Sorry @iain can you elaborate on those last two components? `.../local/file` is what, and `UPLOAD_ADDRESS` is what?

Comment: @Rich_F `path/to/local/file` is the path to the .png file you wish to upload, and `UPLOAD_ADDRESS` is the URL of the site. For example: `curl --verbose -F 'data=@/Users/iain/Pictures/me.png' http://localhost:9292/upload`. The `data` part would correspond to a form field name. See https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76 for more.

Comment: Result: `connected...post...host///accept: */* expect: 100-continue content-type multipart/form-data http/1.1 100 Continue http//1.1 500 Internal Server Error content-type: text.html, length: 177 connection: close, 500 ISE`  So nothing more than the browser report.  Absolutely nothing in `nginx` `error.log`.

Comment: Oops, tested another `.png` file and got a completely different result.  Maybe it's the nature of my test file.  Let me get back to you later with a reply.

Comment: @iain Ya bad file.  It seems a `Fireworks` `.png` file saved is not a `.png` file exported.  Strange.  So it's fixed now.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Bad `.png` file for some reason.  Fixed with a proper file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found out, after reading /var/log/nginx/error.log that a certain client_temp direvtory was being tried by nginx.

"http://somesite/"
2021/03/30 22:11:12 [crit] 7249#7249: *78 open() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000007" failed (20: Not a directory),

There was a file client_temp but it *should* be a directory. After making it a directory and setting the owner to www-data, it worked.